# Compatibility list for Netgear MBR624GU

Tags: compatibility, 3g, mobile-broadband

Does anyone know where I can get a compatibility list for the Netgear MBR624GU 3G router?

Their support says go to http://www.netgear.com/3G but this shows no support for dongles in the UK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While no where online seemed to help, Netgear's tech support gave me this link today which seems to work.
http://powershift.netgear.com/landing/en-us/3g_usb_modems.aspx